# Indents between inline-list elements

Tags: html, css

http://iempire.ru/untitled.html

How to remove the indents between inline **"li"** -elements?

`margin: 0, display:inline-block` have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to tackle this is to add

```
.b-bar-menu { font-size: 0; }
.b-bar-menu li { font-size: 20px; }
```

You might find it cleaner to not specify a class on your list items as they can be targeted using a descendant selector.

Answer (score 4):

They're inline, which means you're seeing the whitespace, not margin, etc.  For example if you changed this:

```
<ul class="b-bar-menu"> 
    <li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
</ul>
```

To this, it'd dissapear:

```
<ul class="b-bar-menu"> 
    <li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li><li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li><li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li><li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
</ul>
```

[You can test out the difference here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Q8pdt/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the spacing without worrying about whitespace in your source, you can remove the inline style and use

```
float: left
```

on your list items while adding

```
overlow:hidden
```

on your ul.  You will have to mess around with relative positioning to get the list centered, however.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to remove the whitespace

```
<div class="l-bar">
  <div class="b-bar">
    <ul class="b-bar-menu">
      <li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li
      ><li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li
      ><li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li
      ><li class="b-bar-menu-item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```